# What is equivalent to "Ctrl + click" of Android Studio in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio

I was using Android Studio. Recently, I learned to write my code in C# using Visual studio.

In Android studio, we have "<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + `click`", But what do we have to use in visual studio?

Comment: Would be useful for future readers to [edit] your question to say _what_ this manipulation achieved (Going to the definition of a method or variable).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ `click` is equivalent to pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in visual studio,

OR

**Right click** and choose **Go to definition**.

Comment: @HằngThành You will be comfort with these, As I was also hesitating this at first.